# Strange artifact in a table

Tags: tables, pdftex

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % allow utf-8 input
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % use 8-bit T1 fonts
\usepackage{hyperref}       % hyperlinks
\usepackage{url}            % simple URL typesetting
\usepackage{booktabs}       % professional-quality tables
\usepackage{amsfonts}       % blackboard math symbols
\usepackage{nicefrac}       % compact symbols for 1/2, etc.
\usepackage{microtype}      % microtypography
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}       % header
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{caption} 
\captionsetup[table]{skip=10pt}
%\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\graphicspath{{media}}     % organize your images and other figures under media/ folder
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l|l|l}
\hhline{|===|}
Operation / List & Singly-linked list & Doubly-linked list \\
\hline
\texttt{prepend} & $\Theta(1)$ & $\Theta(1)$ \\
\texttt{append}  & $\Theta(1)$ & $\Theta(1)$ \\
\texttt{insert$(i)$}  & $\Theta(i) = \mathcal{O}(N)$ & $\Theta(\min(i, N - i)) = \mathcal{O}(N)$ \\
\hline
\texttt{get$(i)$}     & $\Theta(i)$ & $\Theta(\min(i, N - i))$  \\
\hline
\texttt{removeHead} & $\Theta(1)$ & $\Theta(1)$ \\
\texttt{removeTail} & $\Theta(N)$ & $\Theta(1)$ \\
\texttt{removeAt($i$)}   & $\Theta(i) = \mathcal{O}(N)$ & $\Theta(\min (i, N - i)) = \mathcal{O}(N)$ \\
\hline
\texttt{prependCollection} & $\Theta(M)$ & $\Theta(M)$ \\
\texttt{appendCollection}  & $\Theta(M)$ & $\Theta(M)$ \\
\texttt{insertCollection}  & $\Theta(i + M) = \mathcal{O}(N) + \Theta(M)$ & $\Theta(\min (i, N - i) + M) = \mathcal{O}(N) + \Theta(M)$ \\
\hline
\texttt{removeRange$(b, e)$} & $\Theta(b + M) = \mathcal{O}(N) + \Theta
(M)$ & $\Theta(b + M) = \mathcal{O}(N) + \Theta(M)$ \\
\hhline{|===|}
\label{tbl:linked_lists}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

When compiled, it gives me:

[image: Strange artifact]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Remove `\label{…}` that’s out of place there. You label a caption, not a `tabular`.

Comment: Off-topic: There's probably no point in loading the `graphicx` package with the option `pdftex`. For sure, though, since you load the `graphicx` package, there's no reason or point in loading the `graphics` and `epstopdf` packages manually. You may also omit `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` unless your TeX distribution is postively ancient, as `utf8` has been the default input encoding for several years now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @egreg has already noted in a comment, you may fix the immediate typographic problem by taking the `\label` instruction out of the `tabular` environment.

In addition, you may also want to (a) make the table's appearance more attractive by giving it a more open "look" and (b) reduce some of the code clutter in the `tabular` environment, by automating the tasks of switching to a monospaced font in column 1 and switching to inline math mode in columns 2 and 3.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%% (I've tried to simplify the preamble down to the bare minimum)
\usepackage{caption} 
\captionsetup{skip=0.5\baselineskip,labelfont=bf}

%% new:
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
\usepackage{array} % for "\newcolumntype" macro
\newcolumntype{L}{>{$}l<{$}} % left-aligned, automatic math model
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht] % please not "[H]"
\centering
\caption{xyz}
\label{tbl:linked_lists}

\begin{tabular}{@{} >{\ttfamily}l L L @{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{Operation\slash List} &
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Singly-linked list} & 
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Doubly-linked list} \\
\midrule
prepend           & \Theta(1) & \Theta(1) \\
append            & \Theta(1) & \Theta(1) \\
insert(i)         & \Theta(i) = \mathcal{O}(N) 
                    & \Theta(\min(i, N - i)) = \mathcal{O}(N) \\
\addlinespace
get(i)            & \Theta(i) & \Theta(\min(i, N - i))  \\
\addlinespace
removeHead        & \Theta(1) & \Theta(1) \\
removeTail        & \Theta(N) & \Theta(1) \\
removeAt(i)       & \Theta(i) = \mathcal{O}(N) 
                    & \Theta(\min (i, N - i)) = \mathcal{O}(N) \\
\addlinespace
prependCollection & \Theta(M) & \Theta(M) \\
appendCollection  & \Theta(M) & \Theta(M) \\
insertCollection  & \Theta(i + M) = \mathcal{O}(N) + \Theta(M) 
                    & \Theta(\min (i, N - i) + M) = \mathcal{O}(N) + \Theta(M) \\
\addlinespace
removeRange(b,e)  & \Theta(b + M) = \mathcal{O}(N) + \Theta (M) 
                    & \Theta(b + M) = \mathcal{O}(N) + \Theta(M) \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```